# How can I filter or show only one of the duplicates in the results when using Find-Item command?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I used `Find-Item` to get the items on my `sitecore_master_index`. However, the results contains same `ID` but with different languages. I have found out that this item has many language versions in the content tree.

How can I filter or show only one of the duplicates in the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add language en as parameter to your `Find-Item` method .

In this way you show just items in English.

You will have something like:

```
Find-Item 
        -Index sitecore_master_index `
        -Criteria @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = "Template Field"; CaseSensitive = $true},
                  @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_language"; Value = "en"; CaseSensitive = $true}
```